# Python Django OneToOneField nullable value

Tags: python, django

I'm extending the User model to a UserProfile model as below.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

TYPE0 = 0
TYPE1 = 1
PROFILE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (TYPE0, "Old"),
    (TYPE1, "New"),
)
profile_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=PROFILE_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

This part of the code works fine without an error so far.

After this, I want to further extend the `UserProfile` model as below,

```
class Type0User(models.Model):
user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

At this point it throws the error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user_profile' to type0user without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
```

when I try `makemigrations`.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how I may fix it? Also, the motive behind extending the `UserProfile` model further is because I want to two separate models for `Type0User` and `Type1User`. I'm new to database design, so please do point out if the approach I'm taking is not the best way to go about it. Thanks and really appreciate your help and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have existing Type0User rows on your database. As a new column is being added, these rows need to have a default value so they can be populated.

If you are extending your design to support two kinds of users, I suggest add a field to your existing UserProfile model to differentiate the two types.

Comment: Hi navit, I think your first point is valid, I did not add any rows to that table. but is there anyway I can completely overwrite the old model? Because the Type0User model was modified much later. For point, that is actually what I'm trying to do. since the two different user profiles will have their unique fields I need to create two separate models for them and link it to the User model through UserProfile model. Is that a sensible thing to do?

Comment: Just wipe out your data from your database.

Comment: That's kind of the problem because I can't really see any data in it...

Comment: When I try to open the table from the admin site it gives an operational error: no such column as  user_profile_id. really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you have more fields for each type what you are doing is sensible and correct.

Comment: try this into your model user_profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: Hi navit, thanks for taking time to help. However, when I try this it says I can't set primary_key=True and set it to null at the same time...

Comment: Is there a way I can completely drop the current database and recreate it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove the original error. I will create a new project and try again. If the error doesn't come up again I'll accept your original answer. Thanks for making time o help me. really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Anytime.

Comment: Okay, so I created the project again. I think I had screwed up my database somehow because this time it worked with the same code I posted in the question. I will accept your answer, thanks so much.